# Json to google chart table with varying cols and row

Tags: javascript, json, charts, html-table, google-visualization

I have the below json

```
[{
    "dept": "department1",
    "values": [20, 4, 355, 223, 5, 5, 19, 23, 45,11,12]
}, {
    "dept": "department2",
    "values": [5, 2]
}, {
    "dept": "department3",
    "values": [35, 3, 8, 18, 10,3,4, 9]
}, {
    "dept": "department4",
    "values": [36]
}
]
```

The number of departments are varying(not more than 24) and so are count in the values (but not more than 100)

I would like tilt and make it into a google table as below. How can I do it?

```js
department1 , department2, department3, department4
20            5            35            36
4             2            3
355                        8
223                        18
5                          10
5                          3
19                         4
23                         9
45                        
11
12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested for-loops to accomplish this:

```
var file = [{
    "dept": "department1",
    "values": [20, 4, 355, 223, 5, 5, 19, 23, 45,11,12]
}, {
    "dept": "department2",
    "values": [5, 2]
}, {
    "dept": "department3",
    "values": [35, 3, 8, 18, 10,3,4, 9]
}, {
    "dept": "department4",
    "values": [36]
}
]


var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()

for (i = 0; i < file.length; i++){
    //get the department name and add it to the first cell of current column (i)
    sheet.getRange(1, i+1).setValue(file[i].dept)
    for (j = 0; j < file[i].values.length; j++){
     //get the each value of values and add it to the cell in row(j) and column (i)
      sheet.getRange(j+2, i+1).setValue(file[i].values[j])
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add, it has to be displayed inside a <div> of an html. Can SpreadsheepApp embedd this ?

Comment: There's an option in File>Publish to the Web which creates an iframe to embed the sheet. Never worked with this, though.